# Get localized country name from country name

Tags: php, intl

In php, how to convert the English country name to a localized version?

For example, if the locale is set to `fr`, so that `JAPAN` would become `JAPON`.

Update: managed to make it work from the country code but still need country to country code without resorting to a handcrafted array.

```php
echo locale_get_display_region('-JP', 'fr'); // Japon
```

Comment: You can take inspiration or inherit from [`this`](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) link

Comment: I understand how localization works in general, I would rather have an answer to the specific question I've asked.

Comment: Fair enough. A little off-topic but I find it weird that people change the country spellings in their own language itself.

Comment: I'm getting the country name in English but would like to localize it within the customer's invoice: have the country in the same language as the rest of the invoice.

Comment: Ideally mappings are created like `['JAPAN' => 'JAPON']`.

Comment: and I would like to avoid doing the monkey job if it's already been done :)

Comment: I don't think such language conversion exists inbuilt into PHP. The best I can think of right now is to use google translation API.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the help of an external library:

```
composer require league/iso3166
```

```php
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

$data = (new League\ISO3166\ISO3166())->name('Japan');

echo Locale::getDisplayRegion('-' . $data['alpha2'], 'fr'); // Japon
```

Here's link to the package: https://github.com/thephpleague/iso3166